# pandas group by a list of group indces

Tags: python, pandas

Assume I have already got the grouped indices lists of a `dataframe` and I would like to get the sub dataframes using `groupby` or other functions. I know I can use `isin` like `[df[df.index.isin(group)] for group in grouplist]` to query the dataframe several times but it seems to be very slow. How could I get the groups more efficiently?

```
grouplist = [[1],[29, 30, 31],[40],[46, 47, 48, 49],[58, 59],[68, 69, 70],[99, 100, 101],[103]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need `loc`:

```
[df.loc[group] for group in grouplist]
```

EDIT:

For check values in column is faster use:

```
[df[np.in1d(df.A, group)] for group in grouplist]
```

Or:

```
[df[df.A.isin(group)] for group in grouplist]
```

**Timings**:

```
np.random.seed(123)
N = 100000

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.random.randint(150, size=N),
                   'B':np.random.rand(N)})
#print (df)


grouplist = [[1],[29, 30, 31],[40],[46, 47, 48, 49],
             [58, 59],[68, 69, 70],[99, 100, 101],[103]]

def a(df):
    df = df.set_index('A')
    return [df.loc[group] for group in grouplist]

def b(df):
    return [df[df.A.isin(group)] for group in grouplist]

def c(df):
    return [df[np.in1d(df.A, group)] for group in grouplist]


In [84]: %timeit (a(df))
10 loops, best of 3: 117 ms per loop

In [85]: %timeit (b(df))
100 loops, best of 3: 18.3 ms per loop

In [86]: %timeit (c(df))
100 loops, best of 3: 5.44 ms per loop
```

**Caveat**:

Performance really depend on the data - size of DataFrame and number of values in groups in `grouplist`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but what if it is not index but some values of a column?

Comment: Then the fastest is set index first by `df = df.set_index('col')` and then use `loc`

Comment: I am sorry but I found that using `df.set_index('col')` then `loc` is no faster than using `isin`. Maybe it is because my sample data is small?

Comment: Hmmm, I am a bit confused, you need `[df[df.col.isin(group)] for group in grouplist]` and it is slowier as `set_index` + `loc`? Or `[df[df.index.isin(group)] for group in grouplist]` is slowier as `[df.loc[group] for group in grouplist]` ?

Comment: Sorry for poor English, `[df[df.col.isin(group)] for group in grouplist]` costs 0.0339 seconds for 70 rows while `set_index` + `loc` costs 0.0927 seconds.

Comment: Hmmm, what is size of testing dataframe?

Comment: 70 rows. Maybe it should be larger?

Comment: `70` is really small, better is tets `1000` or more. But it depends of real data - number of rows and size of values in groups.

Comment: I have tested in a dataset of 8000+ rows and `[df[df.col.isin(group)] for group in grouplist]` costs 1.057s while  `set_index` + `loc` costs  2.439s.